# ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8) in Rails.cache.delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm immersed in an error than I have no explanation.

The error occurs only in production, in a DigitalOcean server. Rails 5.0 Ruby 2.2.3.
In development, Ubuntu, works fine, tested with no errors and performs caching good.

The problem is when execute `Rails.cache.delete_matched` in production.

I have tried all combinations and I can't get rid off this error.

caching:

```
retorn_text=Rails.cache.fetch("Translation/#{company_id}/#{text_a_traduir}/#{head_locale}/#{locale}", expires_in: 1.year) do
...
end
```

In an `after_save` callback, I want to delete all cache from
`"Translation/#{company_id}/` doing:

```
Rails.cache.delete_matched("Translation/#{company_id}/.+")
```

or

```
Rails.cache.delete_matched("Translation\/#{company_id}\/.*")
```

or

```
Rails.cache.delete_matched(/Translation\/4\/.*/)
```

or

```
reg_exp=/Translation\/#{company_id}\/.*/
Rails.cache.delete_matched(reg_exp)
```

and many other options that I don't remember...

all of these throws the error `ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally it seems I could get it works, I'm not sure if the solution is both of these or only one:

```
Rails.cache.delete_matched(/Translation\/#{company_id}\/.+/)
```

--

```
rails tmp:clear
```

after this change and this tmp clear it works

--

After one month I had to execute `RAILS_ENV=production rails tmp:clear` again to avoid the error. So that it is not solved but now, I know than clearing tmp the problem disappears temporarily

--

No solution with delete_matched, even if force converting to UTF_8 (`text.encode!(Encoding::UTF_8,{invalid: :replace, replace: ""})`

**Solved** clearing cache with `delete` method not `delete_matched`